# automate transfer of tar files over FTP

Tags: bash, scripts, ftp, automation, tar

Every day I have a script making .tar files of aparticualr directory. Once every day, I would like to transfere the new tar file made that day to a remote server over FTP. I would like to make this process automated.

What would be the best way of going about this? Can a bash script be written for this and scheduled it with cron? Is there a tool/app/software that can do this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

Usually these kind of things are best done from the command line

put the example below in a new file under /etc/cron.daily/
and chmod +x filename ,  for it to be executable so that it can be automatically run
on on a daily basis.

```
lftp -e 'put /home/path/yourfile.tar; bye' -u user,password ftp.theserver.com
```

the -e command is to allow you to enter a series of commands.
The commands to be run are declared within the ' '  signs, 
in this example two commands are run in succession each command is separated by the ; sign. The first command uploads a file, the second command disconnects from the ftp server once the upload is complete.

If one would want to add an additional command, for example to browse to a another folder simply add  the change directory command  , "cd folder1/folder2;" in our example the new command would look like this:

```
lftp -e 'cd folder1/folder2; put /home/path/yourfile.tar; bye' -u user,password ftp.theserver.com
```

lftp can take script files as input allowing you to create separate files with commands for it to execute when using the -f option if you feel like having the commands run my lftp separated into a specific file.

if you want to see what commands are available [this](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html) can be help
for generic ftp commands. Commands specific for lftp can be found in the [lftp man page](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)

Comment: sorry, i'm still new to terminal commands. Can you please explain it in more detail. Are those commands inside a bash file that is scheduled in cron? In the 'put /home/path/yourfile.tar; bye' what is the ; bye for? also what are the -e and -u commands mean and how will i be able to specify a directory in the ftp server? ~Thx

Comment: The ; is to separate the 2 commands inside the quotes.  The -e is for specifying commands to execute, and the -u is to say the username and password is coming next.  Usually you can find what the various flags (-e, -u, etc.) do by running `man command`, e.g. `man lftp` on the command line.

Comment: By putting the commands in a text file, say `lftpbackup` inside the `/etc/cron.daily/` folder, and then running `chmod +x lftpbackup`, you will cause the commands in `lftpbackup` to be executed daily.